# does the LFU page reclamation algorithm suffer from belady's anomaly?

Tags: algorithm

i have found online that the LFU is a stack algorithm but when i asked
my lecturer he said it suffers from belady's anomaly,but i have tried a lot of
examples but didn't find any to prove this, so can someone tell me if it does 
indeed suffer from it? or is it a stack algorithm?
if it does suffer from it please show an example,thanks!

Comment: This is probably a better fit for http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/1987/CSD-87-358.pdf section 1.3 defines the stack algorithm and finishes by working through an example of this for LFU. Basically you can maintain a stack as you follow through a trace of memory fetches such that the top i entries of the stack are the entries that will be held in memory if you have capacity for i entries in your memory. Since you can maintain such a stack a larger memory must always hold all of the entries kept in core for any smaller memory and so Belady's anomaly is not possible.

Of course this assumes an exact implementation of LFU with counters of infinite capacity.